# Two null termination signs at the end of a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, null-terminated

I'm learning C via "The C Programming Language" book. During one of the exercises, where it's needed to concatenate two strings, I found that there are two null terminating signs (\0) at the end of a resulting string. Is this normal?

Code for the function:

```
void
copy_str_to_end(char *target, char *destination)
{
        while (*destination != '\0')
                ++destination;
        while ((*destination++ = *target++) != '\0')
                ;
}
```

Output:
`This is a destination. This is a target.` Here's everything seems to be OK, but if I run this function to test:

```
void
prcesc(char *arr)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= strlen(arr) + 1; i++)
                if (arr[i] != '\0')
                        printf("%c", arr[i]);
                else
                        printf("E");
        printf("\n");
}
```

The problem becomes visible: `This is a destination. This is a target.EE` *(E means \0)*
So, should I worry about this or not? And if yes, what's the reason for this thing to happen?

Comment: How is the string stored/assigned in the caller?

Comment: It's nothing to worry about.  A string is an array of characters ending in a null byte.  Whatever happens to lie after the string is not part of the string.  If the buffer was initialized to zero before a string was written into it, the byte after the string will be null.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio It is stored like this: char dest[] = "This is a destination. " and passed as an argument: copy_str_to_end(..., dest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is basically caused by the use of the `<=` operator instead of the `<` operator inside of the `for` loop condition:

```
i <= strlen(arr) + 1
```

`strlen(arr) + 1` gives the amount of elements in the array, `arr` is pointing to in the caller (which actually contains the string).

When you use `i <= strlen(arr) + 1` the loop iterates one time more than expected and you attempt to access an element beyond the bound of the array at the last iteration with

```
if (arr[i] != '\0')
```

since index counting starts at `0`, not `1`.

To access memory beyond the bounds of the array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The extra E in output is because you are running the while loop in prcesc function for i = strlen(arr) + 1 also. strlen returns the length of string say 'n'. So arr[n-1] is the last element of string and all elements from arr[n] are '\0'.
Hence as you are iterating for both arr[n], arr[n+1], you are getting two null characters.

The following function is what you need :

```
void
prcesc(char *arr)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(arr); i++)
            if (arr[i] != '\0')
                    printf("%c", arr[i]);
            else
                    printf("E");
    printf("\n");
}
```